# XNA : 2D Foreach Collision detection issues with a reference of "t" not exiting in current context.

Tags: c#, foreach, xna, collision

My problem is that; when doing collision detection using bounding boxes my second player's arrows are not detecting the fact that they are hitting the "pots" on screen. My first player can hit them just fine, when trying to duplicate the player 1's foreach statement for detecting collisions I have issues and the game1.cs throws errors such as not being able to find variables I have used but I know I have declared. Very confused :3, still a student learning XNA for an assignment; so go easy on me.

```
case MenuScreens.Playing:
                {
                    // This is allowing the player to go back to
                    // The main menu by pressing the escape key. 
                    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                    {
                        menuState = MenuScreens.MainMenu;
                    }
                    //Updating the player1 and player2
                    p.Update(gameTime);
                    p2.Update(gameTime);

                    foreach (Darknut a in darknutList)
                    {
                        // Collision for player to darknut
                        // Note : If bounding box "a" (the darknut) comes into contact with boundingbox "p" (the player)
                        // Then darknut will be destroyed : BUT with reduction in player health. 
                        if (a.boundingBox.Intersects(p.boundingBox))
                        {
                            // Health of the player at "20" hitpoints. Every time the player gets hit by a darknut 
                            // take 20 pixels of the healthbar from 200 in total.
                            p.health -= 20;
                            // Make darknut invisable = deletion
                            a.isVisible = false;
                        }
                        // check to see if any darknuts come in contact with the arrows if so destroy arrow and darknut. 
                        for (int i = 0; i < p.arrowList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            // Returning the element at a specified element in the sequence
                            // Translate :  If any of the darknuts bounding box intersecs with the arrows bounding box 
                            // then destroy both by making the darknut and arrow invisible.  
                            if (a.boundingBox.Intersects(p.arrowList[i].boundingBox))
                            {
                                // when player hits darknut with arrow give them "X" score
                                hud.playerScore += 5;
                                a.isVisible = false;
                                p.arrowList.ElementAt(i).isVisible = false;
                            }

                        }
                        foreach (Darknut t in darknutList)
                        {
                            if (t.boundingBox.Intersects(p2.boundingBox))
                            {
                                // Health of the player at "20" hitpoints. Every time the player gets hit by a darknut 
                                // take 20 pixels of the healthbar from 200 in total.
                                p2.health -= 20;
                                // Make darknut invisable = deletion
                                t.isVisible = false;
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < p2.arrowList.Count; i++)
                            {
                                // Returning the element at a specified element in the sequence
                                // Translate :  If any of the darknuts bounding box intersecs with the arrows bounding box 
                                // then destroy both by making the darknut and arrow invisible.  
                                if (t.boundingBox.Intersects(p.arrowList[i].boundingBox))
                                {
                                    // when player hits darknut with arrow give them "X" score
                                    hud.playerScore2 += 5;
                                    t.isVisible = false;
                                    p2.arrowList.ElementAt(i).isVisible = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        a.update(gameTime);
                        t.update(gameTime);
                    }

                    // Loading Darknuts
                    LoadDarknuts();
                    // Loading Darknuts


                    //Updating the player
                    p.Update(gameTime);
                    //Updating the player2
                    p2.Update(gameTime);

                    // Updating the background
                    bg.Update(gameTime);

                    //  Updating the player health if it hits zero then go to gameover State

                    if (p.health <= 0)
                        menuState = MenuScreens.GameOver;

                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try access to `t` variable without block where declared.

```
case MenuScreens.Playing:
            {
                // This is allowing the player to go back to
                // The main menu by pressing the escape key. 
                KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                {
                    menuState = MenuScreens.MainMenu;
                }
                //Updating the player1 and player2
                p.Update(gameTime);
                p2.Update(gameTime);

                foreach (Darknut a in darknutList)
                {
                    // Collision for player to darknut
                    // Note : If bounding box "a" (the darknut) comes into contact with boundingbox "p" (the player)
                    // Then darknut will be destroyed : BUT with reduction in player health. 
                    if (a.boundingBox.Intersects(p.boundingBox))
                    {
                        // Health of the player at "20" hitpoints. Every time the player gets hit by a darknut 
                        // take 20 pixels of the healthbar from 200 in total.
                        p.health -= 20;
                        // Make darknut invisable = deletion
                        a.isVisible = false;
                    }
                    // check to see if any darknuts come in contact with the arrows if so destroy arrow and darknut. 
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.arrowList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // Returning the element at a specified element in the sequence
                        // Translate :  If any of the darknuts bounding box intersecs with the arrows bounding box 
                        // then destroy both by making the darknut and arrow invisible.  
                        if (a.boundingBox.Intersects(p.arrowList[i].boundingBox))
                        {
                            // when player hits darknut with arrow give them "X" score
                            hud.playerScore += 5;
                            a.isVisible = false;
                            p.arrowList.ElementAt(i).isVisible = false;
                        }

                    }
                    foreach (Darknut t in darknutList)
                    {
                        if (t.boundingBox.Intersects(p2.boundingBox))
                        {
                            // Health of the player at "20" hitpoints. Every time the player gets hit by a darknut 
                            // take 20 pixels of the healthbar from 200 in total.
                            p2.health -= 20;
                            // Make darknut invisable = deletion
                            t.isVisible = false;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < p2.arrowList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            // Returning the element at a specified element in the sequence
                            // Translate :  If any of the darknuts bounding box intersecs with the arrows bounding box 
                            // then destroy both by making the darknut and arrow invisible.  
                            if (t.boundingBox.Intersects(p.arrowList[i].boundingBox))
                            {
                                // when player hits darknut with arrow give them "X" score
                                hud.playerScore2 += 5;
                                t.isVisible = false;
                                p2.arrowList.ElementAt(i).isVisible = false;
                            }
                        }
                        t.update(gameTime);
                    }

                    a.update(gameTime);
                    //t.update(gameTime);
                }

                // Loading Darknuts
                LoadDarknuts();
                // Loading Darknuts


                //Updating the player
                p.Update(gameTime);
                //Updating the player2
                p2.Update(gameTime);

                // Updating the background
                bg.Update(gameTime);

                //  Updating the player health if it hits zero then go to gameover State

                if (p.health <= 0)
                    menuState = MenuScreens.GameOver;

                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a typo in the collision check between the darknuts and player 2's arrows:

```
if (t.boundingBox.Intersects(p.arrowList[i].boundingBox))
```

should be

```
if (t.boundingBox.Intersects(p2.arrowList[i].boundingBox))
```